# JAX-RS with Jersey not working in JBoss AS

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jboss7.x

I'm trying to upload simple REST service onto JBoss AS 7.1 (or TomEE JAX-RS).

My `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.javacodegeeks.jersey.main</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Dependencies on `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Server endpoint:

```java
@Path("account")
public class AccountDetailsService {

    @GET
    @Path("/details/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getAccountDetails(@PathParam("param") String accountName) {
        String output = "Account Name : " + accountName;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
17:37:00,450 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Fai led to start service
jboss.deployment.unit."jersey-example.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
jboss.deployment.unit."jersey-example.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "jersey-example.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea] Caused by:org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
JBAS01123 2: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed. 
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResour ceConfig
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResour ceConfig
com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig
com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppR esourceConfig
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig
com.sun.je rsey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scan(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:209)
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:105)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)[jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more
```

Why does it happen if the same works fine on Tomcat 7 container?

---

update:

```
20:15:03,078 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.dep
loyment.default-host./ROOT: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: Fai
led to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.G
A.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS018038: Root contexts can not be deployed when the virtual host configur
ation has the welcome root enabled, disable it and redeploy
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:57)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:38)
        at org.jboss.msc.inject.CastingInjector.inject(CastingInjector.java:55) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.doInject(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1549) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar
:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$1900(ServiceControllerImpl.java:49) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.ja
r:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.performInjections(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1780) [jbo
ss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1741) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.G
A.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite non-obvious...

1) The following lines was added to web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

2) Next lines from web-xml was commented out:

```
<!--<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.javacodegeeks.jersey.main</param-value>
</init-param>-->
```

3) No need to create a *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* or edit *standalone.xml*.

Comment: If you added a reference to the `com.javacodegeeks.jersey.main` package, you are supposed to have that package in your application.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed

gives you a hint about the problem. JBoss 7 uses RESTEasy as JAX-RS implementation. Your application is using Jersey. And it looks like [Jersey and RESTEasy are not getting on very well in JBoss 7](https://developer.jboss.org/message/744530#744530).

To use Jersey as JAX-RS implementation in JBoss 7, you need to disable RESTEasy, which is bundled by default in JBoss 7.

Try adding the following lines to your `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If it doesn't work, create a file called `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` under your `WEB-INF` folder with the following content to exclude RESTEasy modules:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.async-http-servlet-30" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

---

The error

> JBAS018038: Root contexts can not be deployed when the virtual host configuration has the welcome root enabled, disable it and redeploy

happens when you're trying to deploy an app to root context (either using the name `ROOT.war` or `/` context in `jboss-web.xml`) but the AS welcome page is already occupying that.

To solve it, shut down the server and edit the `standalone.xml`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" 
    native="false">  
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">  
    ...  
</subsystem>
```

For more details, have a look [here](https://developer.jboss.org/people/ozizka/blog/2012/12/21/jbas018038-root-contexts-can-not-be-deployed-when-the-virtual-host-configuration-has-the-welcome-root-enabled-disable-it-and-redeploy).

Comment: I did as you proposed but placed jboss-deployment-structure.xml under META-INF dir. See the qustion update for the error message.

Comment: @AndreasSchwarz The file should be under `WEB-INF`.

Comment: the same error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS018038: Root contexts can not be deployed when the virtual host configuration has the welcome root enabled, disable it and redeploy

Comment: @AndreasSchwarz Please edit your question and post your `standalone.xml`.

Comment: @AndreasSchwarz Looks like the first error is already solved. But the second one is very strange and shouldn't happen with the default `standalone.xml`.