# Jboss 7.0I'm trying to upload simple REST service onto JBoss AS 7.0 Jersey is not working in JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss, jersey, redhat

I'm trying to upload simple REST service maven project onto JBoss AS 7.0 since resteasy jar providing security issue, i am trying to replace resteasy with jersey.
1.My web.xml file::

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
 <display-name>addjersey</display-name>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

2.My jboss-deployment-structure.xml file :::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="resteasy" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
        </exclusions>
        <local-last value="true" />
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

3. My pom.xml file :::

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>addjersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>addjersey</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

4. Server end point :::

```
public class RestApiImpl {
    @GET
    @Path("/merchant")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMerchantDetails() {
      System.out.println("request received");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

When i run jboss server, the war getting deployed without any errors But when i make restcall  *http://localhost:8080/addjersey/merchant/* , response from server is 404 and there are no exceptions or logs are rolling.
I am new to JBOSS and I cant figure out what  exactly iam missing here or need to add any additional configurations ?.
I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739152/jax-rs-with-jersey-not-working-in-jboss-as) but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working for me after i made the changes to the following files
1.pom.xml file:::

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>addjersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>addjersey</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>addjersey</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

2.ApplicationConfig.java:::

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(RestApiCall.class);
        return resources;
    }

}
```

3.web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>addjersey</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->
     <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param> 
</web-app>
```

4.Server End point ::

```
@Path("/api")
public class RestApiCall extends Application {
    @GET
    @Path("/merchant")
    public String printAccountDetails() {
      System.out.println("request received");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

There is no configuration required for jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't have an Application class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/your-rest-path")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
}
```

or a servlet mapping:

```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/your-rest-path/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Please read the documentation.

Personally I like the first approach.

Please read the documentation to find out more

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform_continuous_delivery/18/html/developing_web_services_applications/developing_jax_rs_web_services